# How can I tell what version of SMB is negotiated when I connect to a share from macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, smb, file-sharing

I have quite a few file servers at work that serve up files over SMB/CIFS.

How can I tell what version is negotiated when someone says that I need to be sure I'm connecting over SMB version 3 to get best performance?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `smbutil` command can dump the attributes for all shares or you can target one particular share and parse out the version string:

```
smbutil statshares -a
```

In the case of the listing below:

```
site-test-mbp01:~ me$ df
Filesystem                                           512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity  iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1                                          975210568  368841648  602865928    38%  1808606 9223372036852967201    0%   /
devfs                                                       706        706          0   100%     1222                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4                                          975210568    2097200  602865928     1%        2 9223372036854775805    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts                                                    0          0          0   100%        0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                                 0          0          0   100%        0                   0  100%   /home
/dev/disk3s1                                         7813365344 1387760392 6424657392    18%    28307 9223372036854747500    0%   /Volumes/apfs
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-03-29-120539@/dev/disk1s1  975210568  367917520  602865928    38%  1809465 9223372036852966342    0%   /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/site-test-mbp01/2018-03-29-120539/Macintosh HD
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-03-23-083810@/dev/disk1s1  975210568  348612592  602865928    37%  1755978 9223372036853019829    0%   /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/site-test-mbp01/2018-03-23-083810/Macintosh HD
//me@file-nasuni/abc                              2147409920     227552 2147182368     1%   113774          1073591184    0%   /Volumes/abc
```

To target the Nasuni share "abc"

```
smbutil statshares -m /Volumes/abc/ | awk '/SMB_VERSION/{print $2}'
```

The command shows I'm negotiated a SMB_3.02 connection to that storage appliance share.

Comment: @colin I rolled back your edit. Just tried on 13.4.1, worked without `sudo` (from a non-admin account).

Comment: @nohillside, the command runs, but it gives an error, as stated in my edit comments.

Comment: @colin I don't get the error at all, just the expected output?! Do you have volumes mounted by another user?

Answer (score 4):

This is an example how `smbutil statshares -a` looks like on MacOS 10.15.4:

```
~ $ smbutil statshares -a

==================================================================================================
SHARE                         ATTRIBUTE TYPE                VALUE
==================================================================================================
SomeShareName
                              SERVER_NAME                   MYSERVER._smb._tcp.local
                              USER_ID                       502
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB1_ENABLED
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB2_ENABLED
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB3_ENABLED
                              SMB_VERSION                   SMB_3.02
                              SMB_SHARE_TYPE                DISK
                              SIGNING_SUPPORTED             TRUE
                              EXTENDED_SECURITY_SUPPORTED   TRUE
                              LARGE_FILE_SUPPORTED          TRUE
                              OS_X_SERVER                   TRUE
                              DFS_SUPPORTED                 TRUE
                              FILE_LEASING_SUPPORTED        TRUE
                              MULTI_CREDIT_SUPPORTED        TRUE
                              ENCRYPTION_SUPPORTED          TRUE
                              ENCRYPTION_REQUIRED           TRUE

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a network sniffer like Wireshark, filter as `smb||smb2` and see in the `negotiate response` the dialect that the server chosen.