# How can I fix things when Catalina will not connect to smb shares?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, smb

Based on proposed solutions at:
[What causes some Network Drives using SMB no longer connect to macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362739/what-causes-some-network-drives-using-smb-no-longer-connect-to-macos-catalina)

I have edited the /etc/nsmb.conf which worked for about seven (7) days, and now nothing.  I verified that the edited lines are intact after a system update from apple.

I am using Samba version 4.7.6.

On server side I set the smb.conf file in GLOBAL settings to include the line:

min protocol = SMB2
(I have also tried, min protocol = SMB3) different server, same result (no connection).

somewhat at wit's end.  May have to roll back from Catalina.

I can access the servers from android devices and Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:   Kept working on this and deleted the existing servers from the list on the "Connect to Server" (FINDER, GO, CONNECT TO SERVER) list.  Then browsed for servers and VOILA, CONNECTED!!!!

Comment: Be sure to come back and mark this check mark as solved. We ge the question title to denote that. Here’s how to versions if you want to record details while it works. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320841/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-smb-is-negotiated-when-i-connect-to-a-share-from