# Mountpoint of network shares

Tags: filesystem, mount, smb

Where exactly are network shares, more specifically samba shares located in the file system tree? I have some trouble with hidden samba shares on a windows server that I need a lower-level look at than the finder can give me.

Comment: Wouldn't you enter `mount` to see the mount point? Or more specifically, enter `mount | grep smbfs`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson `mount -t smbfs` :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Finder, use the go to folder (shift-command-g) menu to navigate to /Volumes and see the mounts.

- [Mounting Samba shares under /Volumes without GUI fluff](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282770/)

`mount -t smbfs` shows some detailed information [if you need a command-line solution to then stat the share…](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320842/5472)

It’s not clear what lower level access you seek, but let me know if you make an edit to the question to clarify.